# Is $\Pr(X<Y|X<a)\geq \Pr(X<Y)$?

Tags: probability

Given that $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative random variables, and $a$ is a non-negative constant, is $\Pr(X<Y|X<a)\geq \Pr(X<Y)$? I mean, is that $X<a$ gives useful informaiton on the guess of $X<Y$?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily. It holds of course if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

But if they are *not* independent, anything can happen. Suppose for example that $Y=X^2$ holds and $a=1$ ...

---

In the **independent** case, note that
$$ \mathrm P(X<Y \mid X<a) ~\ge~ \mathrm P(Y\ge a\mid X<a) ~=~ \mathrm P(Y\ge a\mid X\ge a) ~\ge~ \mathrm P(X<Y \mid X\ge a) $$
where the middle equals sign is because $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Since $\mathrm P(X<Y)$ is a weighted average of the two extremes of this inequality, it cannot be larger than the left-hand side.

Comment: thanks for answering me so quickly. Yes, I checked my problem, it's indeed that X and Y are independent. Previously, I thought it is correct intuitively. Is there any way to prove it mathematically? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @LiuYing: Answer updated.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help to explain. I got your point now.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help to explain. But the last ineuqality, $P(Y\geq a|X\geq a)\leq P(X<Y|X\geq a)$, is this correct? Given the knowledge that $X\geq a$, the probability of $Y\geq a$ is greater than the probability of $Y>X$, right? @Heinning

Comment: @LiuYing: Oops, I seem to have reversed some of the inequalities (I drew a diagram and accidentally shaded the $X>Y$ part instead of $X<Y$, which confused me).  Now I think I have crosschecked both ends. If $Y\ge A$ and $X<a$ then certainly $X<Y$. And if $X<Y$ and $X\ge a$ then certainly $Y\ge a$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Markholm, yes, I also got it after reading your inequalities. Thank you very much for your kind help, really appreciated :)